# Command or Environment for Composing Sonnets

Tags: environments, verse

I was wondering if a command or environment might be possible to accommodate the writing of short verse, one that would provide rhyme scheme, even for missing lines.  Maybe via an array somehow?  My attempt for a sonnet was thwarted by the 9-argument limit, but I suspect this is not best approach anyway.  The \ph (placeholder} feature maybe could be built into the environment?

What appeals to me about the below is how clean the CODE looks; helpful when composing.  (I recognise LaTeX is not an environment some people would choose for the writing process.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\sonnet}[9]{
 {#1 \textsuperscript{\emph{a}} \\}
 {#2 \textsuperscript{\emph{b}} \\}
 {#3 \textsuperscript{\emph{a}} \\}
 {#4 \textsuperscript{\emph{b}} \\}
 {#5 \textsuperscript{\emph{b}} \\}
 {#6 \textsuperscript{\emph{c}} \\}
 {#7 \textsuperscript{\emph{b}} \\}
 {#8 \textsuperscript{\emph{c}} \\}
 {#9 \textsuperscript{\emph{c}} \\}
 }
 
 \newcommand{\ph}{{\underline{\hspace{5em}}}\ }

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}

\sonnet
 {When writing verse, \LaTeX\ as often helps}
 {As hinders, fostering the nascent notion}
 {As fast as the imagination whelps,}
 {And no philosophy shows such devotion}
 {To the \ph, amidst the commotion}
 {Of composition, so needful to poet}
 {And coder alike, adrift in an ocean}
 {Of signs and signifiers, content to go it}
 {Alone, 'till 9-argument limit blow it---}
 
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `reledmac` was designed for this. You can set up a stanza with a certain pattern of indents.

Comment: Why not use one of the packages dedicated to typesetting poetry: verse, gmverse, poemscol, poetry, poetrytex?

Comment: I don't think I need anything nearly so robust as regards formatting; my idea was more about the composing process - a tool for the poet, not typesetter - a simple command or environment one could use that lays out the rhyme scheme beside lines that are themselves in various stages of completion.